# Augmented Dickey Fuller Test Results for Interpretation of the Differenced Series

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, stationarity, finance, augmented-dickey-fuller

I wish to do a study on the similarities and differences in ACF/CCF coefficients of a collection of stock market indices. I've mostly taught myself the process which I've outline below so any guidance on misinterpretations and/or wrong intuition would be greatly appreciated.

**Approach:**
My understanding of (one of) the way(s) to do this would be:

1. To apply the large sample properties and infer significance of sample ACF/CCF coefficients we require stationarity of (at least one of in the CCF case) the series. So I plot each series, (raw, detrended and first differenced) along with it's autocorrelation function. An example for the S&P500 is shown below.

[image]

2. Eyeballing the graphs indicates that the first two series (raw and detrended) are not stationary, but the rightmost first differenced series looks like it's probably stationary in mean and also displays some statistically significant ACF coefficients.
3. We wish to test this so that we can test for statistically significant autocorrelations (and subsequently for significant cross-correlations) across different indices. Therefore we conduct an augmented dickey fuller test on the differenced series to investigate if it is in fact stationary in mean.
4. We now conduct an augmented dickey fuller test on the first differenced series using the following R code:

   `adf.test(diff(SPX), k=75)`

   If the p-values are returned as under 0.05 then we can reject the null hypothesis that the differenced series is non-stationary (in mean) and we can continue to test for similarities in statistically significant ACF and CCF coefficients of the different indices using 5% confidence interval bounds $\pm\frac{2}{\sqrt[]{n}}$.

**Questions:**

1. Need I also test for stationarity of variance or other higher moments or does the ADF cover me to the extent that I am safe to proceed with comparing statistically significant ACF/CCF coefficients?
2. I arbitrarily chose k=75 for the ADF time lags to test for - how ought I determine how many lags are appropriate?
3. If I were to conduct this process for say, index A and index B, and say they each had a statistically significant lag t-1 autocorrelation coefficient of same direction and similar magnitude, would I be correct in saying that the growth rate of index A at $t$ is dependent on it's $t-1$ growth rate in a similar way to that of index B's $t$ growth rate's dependence on it's $t-1$ growth rate? I want to check my interpretation of what I'm finding as my goal is to ultimately partition a large collection of indices by showing some "time-series-property-defined" group structure.

Many thanks in advance!